# Align 3 different sized Divs

Tags: javascript, html, css

https://i.stack.imgur.com/iETqe.png

I currently have 3 divs in a page, I want to align them as displayed in the link.

Div1 has

```
    style="float:left;"
```

Div2

```
    style="float:right;"
```

But when I place Div3 it's content appears right under Div2 (even if I set the div's attribute to float:left)

Isn't there any easy way to group these on my page?

Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/3pcD4/

Comment: ....code? HTML, CSS, jsfiddle.net?

Comment: try `clear:left;` on div 3

Comment: A fiddle would be handy... Otherwise, at least some HTML and CSS code that you've tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to clear the float, otherwise the third div will float directly "after" the second one.
add `clear:both;`  to the style of div3 and it will float correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You need to clear floated divs to jump back into the regular dom flow.

http://codepen.io/isdampe/pen/savAh